# c++ lua error on setting global variable

Tags: c++, lua

I have the folowing code:

```
lua_State *lua;
lua = lua_open();
luaL_openlibs(lua);

std::string code = "print(gvar)\n"
    "function test()\n"
    "print(gvar)\n"
    "end\n";

if(!luaL_loadstring(lua, code.c_str())){
    if (lua_pcall(lua, 0, 0, 0)){
        const char* error = lua_tostring(lua, -1); 
        lua_pop(lua, 1);
    }
}

lua_pushstring(lua, "100");
lua_setglobal(lua, "gvar");
if (lua_pcall(lua, 0, 0, 0)){
    const char* error = lua_tostring(lua, -1); // returns "attempt to call a nil value"
    lua_pop(lua, 1);
}

lua_close(lua);
```

Calling functions and getting global variables works fine, but when i try to set global variable i get "attempt to call a nil value". And i cant understand why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if(!luaL_loadstring(lua, code.c_str())){
    if (lua_pcall(lua, 0, 0, 0)){
        const char* error = lua_tostring(lua, -1); 
        lua_pop(lua, 1);
    }
}
```

This code loads string into a anonymous function using `luaL_loadstring()`, puts it on the stack and then executes the function using `lua_pcall(lua, 0, 0, 0)`.

```
lua_pushstring(lua, "100");
lua_setglobal(lua, "gvar");
if (lua_pcall(lua, 0, 0, 0)){
    const char* error = lua_tostring(lua, -1); // returns "attempt to call a nil value"
    lua_pop(lua, 1);
}
```

This piece of code pushes string onto the stack then sets global variable `gvar`. There should be nothing on the stack after call to `lua_setglobal()`. The var is already there.

Now after that you try to call a function which is at the top of the stack with `lua_pcall`, but the stack is empty - that's why you get `attempt to call a nil value` message.

Comment: oh, i see, thank you. I thought i needed to call lua_pcall so that variable will actually be added.

Comment: Nope, you use `lua_pcall()` to call functions, all other things are just executed.