# C++ Lua, fetching global string

Tags: c++, string, variables, lua, global

In my script I've got this global variable:

```
name = "Stabilizer"
```

And, I'm trying to fetch this variable in c++, like so:

```
char* CeScript::GetGlobalString(char* pName)
{
    luaL_loadstring(L, m_sScript.c_str());

    lua_getglobal(L, pName);

    return (char*)lua_tostring(L, -1);
}
....
char* _name = pScript->GetGlobalString("name");
```

But, lua_tostring returns a null ptr, suggesting that the global variable could not be found.

What could be the issue?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The loadstring just compiles the string into a Lua chunk, but to exec the chunk you have to call lua_pcall. Do that just after the loadstring, or assign it to a global or ref in registry if you need to pcall it repeatedly.

For code samples see other SO posts for keywords "luaL_loadstring lua_pcall" such as 
[LUA_MULTRET not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20827096/lua-multret-not-working-as-expected/20829023#20829023) and [c++ lua error on setting global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101713/c-lua-error-on-setting-global-variable/18102190#18102190).

Comment: Thank you for your time, at the moment I can't test this, but as soon as I can, I will.